# Eclipse: Combined Groovy and Gradle editing support

Tags: eclipse, gradle, groovy

I know that there is very good Groovy/Gradle support in IntelliJ IDEA, but I'm trying to out find how far Eclipse can go currently. This is my current setup:

- Buildship plugin: Included by default and adds basic Gradle mechanisms to Elipse, almost no support in editor (code completion, documentation, formatting etc.).
- EGradle Editor plugin: Understands the Gradle DSL and gives code completions / documentation for the Gradle API, does not understand Groovy itself.
- Groovy Development Tools plugin by Pivotal: Good Groovy support with code completions, formatting of Groovy code etc.

What is missing now is a combination of the last two points. The editors of each plugin understands either Gradle or Groovy, but not both. I have seen that there is some support for DSL descriptors in the Groovy plugin, but I cannot find anywhere in the internet a DSL descriptor for Gradle. I have found out that there was some support for such a DSL descriptor in the now deprecated Gradle integration plugin for the STS (Spring Tool Suite by Pivotal) which was again removed later (keyword: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.dsld).

So the overall question is roughly: Is there a Gradle DSLD for the Groovy Development Tools plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add DLSD for Gradle to Eclipse.  At the time of this post, there is nothing built-in to the [Groovy Development Tools for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovy-development-tools).

You'll need to open you Gradle build scripts in the Groovy editor, not the default Gradle editor.

First roadblock is making the Gradle types available to the DSLD.  This can be done by adding "gradleApi()" dependency to your Gradle dependencies block.  Then you can try this out as a Groovy DSLD file in your project (it is a bit bare bones at this time):

```
def isBuildScript = fileExtension('gradle') & (~fileName('settings.gradle'))

contribute(isBuildScript & isThisType()) {
  delegatesTo 'org.gradle.api.Project'

  method name: 'apply', type: void, namedParams: [plugin: String]
}

contribute(isBuildScript & enclosingCallName('configurations') & inClosure() & currentType('org.gradle.api.Project')) {
  setDelegateType('org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer')
}

contribute(isBuildScript & enclosingCallName('dependencies') & inClosure() & currentType('org.gradle.api.Project')) {
  setDelegateType('org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler')
}

contribute(isBuildScript & enclosingCallName('repositories') & inClosure() & currentType('org.gradle.api.Project')) {
  setDelegateType('org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler')
}

contribute(fileName('settings.gradle') & isThisType()) {
  setDelegateType('org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings')
}
```

There is more discussion of this here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6089